# Django, viewing uploaded files and videos

Tags: python, html, django, upload, filefield

I would like to be able to view my uploaded files. I really have a poor grasp of what I am doing.

views.py

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() 
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics')) 
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/model_form_upload.html', {'form':form}) 


def file_preview(request):
    videos = Document.objects.all()     
    context = {'videos':videos} 
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/video.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to = 'documents/')
    upload_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

forms.py

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document 
        fields = ['docfile']
```

I have uploaded videos and pictures.

As the files are passed onto the HTML, I can only see the names of the files I uploaded. I can't click on the links and view the files.

I would like to have an actual video player to play the videos, or view the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url) attribute of [FileField](https://kite.com/python/docs/django.forms.fields.FileField) in your template and pass that URL to your favorite player js library.